# Regex matches which are not followed by a string

Tags: regex

I am using the following regex for detecting negative numbers:

```
([-]([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+))
```

But I want to skip the matches which are followed by $.
If i use the folowing regex:

```
([-]([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)[^\$])
```

It will match correctly the positions but will include the following character. 
For example in expression:

```
-0.6+3 - 3.0$
```

it will match:

```
-0.6+
```

I want to match only

```
-0.6
```

Comment: Note that anything in `()` will be captured as a group.

Comment: You should accept any one of the answers if it helped you

Answer (score 6):

```
([-]([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)(?!\$)
```

You need a `negative lookahead` here which will not consume and only make an assertion.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the $ from the group:

```
([-]([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+))[^\$]
```

You could use this simplified regex:

```
(-[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)(?!\$)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex from [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html) with just minus at the beginning, and a `\b` added at the end in order to stop before *any* non-word character:

```
[-][0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?\b
```

This regex also captures the numbers with exponent part.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/bS4xJ9/2)